# Small images causes Too much page load time

Tags: php, codeigniter, firefox, gzip, html

Below is the page load time of "Net" tab from Firebug. 
I dont know the reason why the small sized images took too mush time to load.
I used gzip compression on my .htaccaess file. Works good in Chrome, but issues in firefox.

[image]

Screenshot of my site

Comment: Maybe a link ? We cant see much from that screenshot that could help say why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the reason on search. This is due to more http requests.
To reduce the request, CSS sprites can be used to combine small image into one large image.